# Writing an equals method inside of an Abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

So this is more of a conceptual question. 
I have Abstract class `A`, and Classes `B` and `C` extend `A`.

Both `B` and `C` only have 1 instance variable called `var` in both classes, and both have `.getVar` methods. An object is equal to an instance of `B` if that object is an instance of `B` and both instances have equal values for `var`. The same is true for `C`.

Is there a way I can write a `.equals(Object object)` method inside of my Abstract class so I don't have to write what is basically the same method with the same functionality in both classes?

Comment: The right way to do this would be an abstract class based off A that B and C both inherit from.  So A->Z->(B and C), and Z implements the 'equals' operator and contains 'var'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A` has an `abstract` method `getVar()` that both `B` and `C` provide the implementation of, we can utilize that in `A#equals` when equating the two objects. Because only objects of type `B` can be equal to another object of type `B` (same goes for `C`), we can simply compare the classes of each object; if the classes differ, then they cannot be equal.

```
// You didn't specify what type 'var' is.
// B and C both have an implementation for this method.
public abstract T getVar();

@Override
public final boolean equals(Object o) { // Is final so B and C can't override it.
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        // This will ensure that B cannot be equal to C or A, and vice versa.
        return false;
    }

    // o must be of the type B or C, so it's safe to cast to A here.
    return getVar().equals(((A) o).getVar());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you're looking for appears to be a way to define an abstract method `getVar` in your parent class `A`, and provide implementations in your subclasses `B` and `C`, with the parent class' `equals` method depending on the value returned by `getVar`. This is complicated by the fact that each subclass may have a different return type for `getVar`.

The solution is to make `A` a generic class, allowing for the return type of `getVar` to itself be generic. Then, you can simply reference the `getVar` method from `equals`, without worrying about its specific type:

```
public abstract class A<T> {
    public abstract T getVar();

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getVar().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        A<?> other = (A<?>) obj;
        return getVar().equals(other.getVar());
    }
}
```

In the example above, you'll notice `getVar` returns the generic type `T`. That will be specified when you define your subclasses:

```
public class B extends A<Integer> {
    private int var = 0;
    public B(int var) { this.var = var; }

    @Override
    public Integer getVar() { return var; }
}

public class C extends A<String> {
    private String var = "";
    public C(String var) { this.var = var; }

    @Override
    public String getVar() { return var; }
}
```

That's all it takes! Unless you choose to specifically override `equals` in your subclass, it will fall back to the method declared in `A` when `.equals` is invoked on an instance of your subclass. Full test case included below.

```js
public class Tester042219 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B x = new B(1);
        B x2 = new B(1);
        B x3 = new B(99);

        System.out.println("B == B: Works? " 
            + (x.equals(x2) && !x.equals(x3)));

        C y = new C("A");
        C y2 = new C("A");
        C y3 = new C("AAAA");

        System.out.println("C == C: Works? " 
            + (y.equals(y2) && !y.equals(y3)));
    }

    public static abstract class A<T> {
        public abstract T getVar();

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + getVar().hashCode();
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) return true;
            if (obj == null) return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

            A<?> other = (A<?>) obj;
            return getVar().equals(other.getVar());
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A<Integer> {
        private int var = 0;
        public B(int var) { this.var = var; }

        @Override
        public Integer getVar() { return var; }
    }

    public static class C extends A<String> {
        private String var = "";
        public C(String var) { this.var = var; }

        @Override
        public String getVar() { return var; }
    }

}
```